# why does date time function don't need migration when I set it to default?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

In Django when I set my date/time to default 
 default=datetime.now()
It automatically migrated in models.py. Why I do not need to do migration for it?

Comment: Some parameters don't need any migration procedure. `default` parameter just specifies what value to store in db when your form is going to get saved. It act at form level that's why it don't need any migration.

Answer (score 2):

just change `default=datetime.now()` to `default=datetime.now`

Now I really think, you meant **why there is always a new migrations for this model ?**

It is beacuse you are changing the model structure by doing

> `default=datetime.now()` *this, actually calls the function whenever
>   this line is read,*

whereas what you want to do is :

> `default=datetime.now` *this will be called when a new instance is
>   created.*